# Reduce the verticle text line spacing in a Chart Title that has two lines

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

Using VBA, how would you decrease the spacing between two lines of text in the Chart title? I generated a chart title using VBA but the vertical spacing is too large. 
Also, is it possible to change the Chart title box height and width using VBA, which may fix the problem?

Comment: I tried this but cant seem to make it work:  .VerticalAlignment = xlTop

Comment: Please edit your question to add clarification. Your question should have all the info needed to address the problem, so people don't have to read all the comments to figure out what your really need.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible.